# I need help using a Resource Bundle where I can change the language in my java program

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

Question:
 Create a new project in Eclipse
Modify the JFrame from the previous slide. Add a JComboBox with “English” and “French” listed . Use Resource bundles to translate the english JButton to French “Montrer tous les Locales” when the French option is selected. The JComboBox should also be internationalized to read “Francais” and “Anglais” when French is the selected language.

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Exercise2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private ResourceBundle res;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JButton button;
JFrame frame;
JTextArea ta;
JLabel label;
JComboBox<String> combo;
String[] array;

Locale[] availableLocales = Calendar.getAvailableLocales();

public Exercise2() {
    Locale loc = new Locale("de","DE"); //create Locale for German in Germany

    getRes();
    setRes(ResourceBundle.getBundle("ProgramResource",loc)); //Create resource bundle

    JLabel greetLabel = new JLabel(getRes().getString("greeting")); //get value for greeting key value

    JButton computeButton = new JButton(getRes().getString("computeButton")); //button key value

    getContentPane().add(greetLabel);
    getContentPane().add(computeButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    String[] array = { "English", "French" };
    combo = new JComboBox<String>(array);

    label = new JLabel(getRes().getString("greeting"));
    button = new JButton(getRes().getString("Button"));

    ta = new JTextArea(10,12);
    ta.setEditable(false);

    button = new JButton();
    button.setText("List all Locales");
    button.addActionListener(this);

    JScrollPane output = new JScrollPane(combo);

    p.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(output);
    p.add(combo);
    c.add(p);

    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method stub
    if (a.getActionCommand().equals("List all Locales")) {

        for (int i = 0; i < availableLocales.length; i++) {

            ta.append(availableLocales[i].getDisplayName() + "\n");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exercise2 myLocaleTest = new Exercise2();
    myLocaleTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public ResourceBundle getRes() {
    return res;
}

public void setRes(ResourceBundle res) {
    this.res = res;
}
}
```

So I keep getting an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ProgramResource, locale de_DE
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
    at Exercise2.<init>(Exercise2.java:42)
    at Exercise2.main(Exercise2.java:89)
```

I don't know what it means and every time I change something it just doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a textfile with text like eg.button=france and class for ResourceBundle like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;


public class ProgramProperties_de extends PropertyResourceBundle {

  public ProgramProperties_de() throws IOException {
    super(ProgramProperties_de.class.getResourceAsStream("ProgramProperties_de.txt"));
  }
}
```